# New records are not being entered using selenium script

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have written a selenium script which is working fine, the script is being used to login in to the web app and then create a record.

On executing script I get the message record has been created successfully but 
record doesnt exist. However when i manually create that record it comes up on front end is also present in database.

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming there is a form with “submit” button which you have automated to create the record. 
just do one thing apply wait condition after clicking on submit button
because sometime what happen if you click on some button and quit the browser the action is not completed and script get passed.

Comment: After creation of record I am not ending session and there is a pop alert I am also handling that.